# Sticky header animation working when scrolling down but not when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-morning-3f09m?file=/src/App.tsx

So, I have a sticky header which should appear once the user has scrolled a X amount of pixels (420px in this example). Once it hits 420px, it shows an animation sliding the header down. When I scroll the screen back up, however, the sticky header just "disappears" in a very cold way. The idea is that it would also "slide" up and disappear in a reverse way as it appeared. An example of what I want to achieve -> https://www.pretto.fr/
I want exactly this, for the header to slide when it comes down but when I scroll back up, for it scroll up disappearing.

The difference is that in this website the sticky header and the "main" header are two different components it seems. On my website, they are just one, and I'm just using props for it to go from `position: relative;` to `position: sticky;`

My header:

```
function Header(props: HeaderProps): React.ReactElement {
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  const trackScroll = () => {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
      return
    } else {
      setSticky(window.scrollY >= 420)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Container id="container" sticky={sticky} className={`${sticky ? 'sticky' : ''}`}>
    ...
```

And my styled-components styles...

```
const smoothScroll = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
`

const Container = styled.div<{ sticky?: boolean }>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 6rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: ${props => (props.sticky ? 'sticky' : 'relative')};
  top: 0px;
  height: 97px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
  background: ${props => (props.sticky ? 'white' : 'inherit')};

  &.sticky {
    animation: ${smoothScroll} 500ms;
  }
`
```

So the nice "sliding down" animation works once I scroll down to 420px. But as soon as I scroll back up it just disappears instead of "sliding up". Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: If you go to the site you provided, scroll down and take a full size screenshot in the chrome developer tab - you can notice that there are two navigations on the site at the same time. The second sticky navigation just changes transform like yours but without the animation part - the animation is done with a transition: transform ease 300ms

Comment: @SimonDubek yes I mentioned that. My question was whether it was possible to achieve this animation without having 2 navs...

Answer (score 1):

I added another sticky navigation that uses an inline style to change the transform and a transition to animate it. You could also achieve this by changing the position and some other styles on the original navigation and thereby get rid off the second sticky navigation but I think this is much more clear.

Would this work for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-raman-qtitt

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this. The demo is not working though, is it working on your side? Looks like it's some problem with the 'stickyStyle'

Comment: It should be working now, btw sorry for not reading your question properly, I was just too much in a hurry to answer and I just skipped the part where you acknowledged the two navigation system - which is completely dumb of me to want to answer a question  I didn't properly read.